# How to associate a Build to the test plan in Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, tfsbuild, microsoft-test-manager

I am new using Microsoft Test tools, please help:

When trying to run a test case from MTM, I am receiving the following warning message:

> Cannot create automated test run.  A build associated with the active test plan is required to submit an automated test run

Background info:

- I have created a Build definition in VS 2010
- I have created a Build service host with Agents:Controller and Agent
- When I open MTM>Testing Center>Properties Build Configurations I can see my build definition selected in "Filter for Builds:"

Problem:
In  MTM>Testing Center>Properties Build Configurations > "**Build in use:"** is set to **None**, when I open Assign Build section I have not available build

Answer (score 2):

Just as a pointer, in case someone finds this (unanswered) post:

"To get automated tests working from Microsoft Test Manager you need to associate a build containg the automation component with a test plan. This tells MTM where to find the code for the automated tests. Then you also need a test environment which MTM will communicate with and run the tests on.

The following article describes how to setup a test plan to run automated tests: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553270.aspx"

from [this post in msdn.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e7605625-847e-493f-b3c0-799d2eb88021/getting-the-following-error-while-running-an-automated-test-case-using-a-test-manager-cannot-create?forum=vstsstart)

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is an issue with your permissions in TFS. You need to have `View builds` permission to the Build you have assigned in the `Build definition`.

Ask from your admin to give you the permission needed, or if you can do it by yourself:

1. Open `Visual Studio 2010`
2. Go to `Team Explorer` --> `Builds` --> and right click to the Build you want
3. Select `Security` and give the appropriate permission to the User that is `Owner` of the Test Plan in MTM.

Comment: I make sure to check permisions, my username is almost in every Collection group, TFS Group and Team Projec Group, I "Allow"ed everything with the word "Build" I Share the Build Drop Folder as instructed and after I Queue the Build it gets broken Please check this .gif file [link](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3TA6vyvJvAgRWdIM08yU3RfeVE)

Comment: Ok, now I think you are facing another problem. To get available builds in MTM you need at least one successful build. Do you have any? If your build is always failing, then you should post a new question (or edit this one) on how to fix this.

Comment: thank you very much for you post, I will not mark this as an accepted answer yet, but I am going to follow your suggestion by posting another question

Comment: You 're welcome. If you found it helpful you can up vote it :).

Comment: I created another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028220/how-can-my-first-build-definition-work-if-is-getting-broken-after-queue-a-new-bu)