# How can my first Build definition work if is getting broken after "Queue a new Build" in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, tfsbuild, microsoft-test-manager

I am trying to use my automated coded UI test (CUIT) with Microsoft Test Manager 2010 in a physical enviroment.

- Created a Build definition
- Defined a drop folder for Builds and
- Shared this folder as recomended [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb778394%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- Created a Build service in TFS 2010 as "Interactive Process"
- Created a Build Controler
- Created a Agent Controler

I dont remember in which order (In case this is important)

ERRORS FROM **MS Visual Studio 2010** (For IMAGE Plese go [HERE](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3TA6vyvJvAgRWdIM08yU3RfeVE/edit))

Error One (1)

> TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \Test Sample\Project1BuildOne: There was no endpoint listening athttp://us07ws45510012:9191/Build/v3.0/Services/Controller/1 that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Or

Error Two (2)

> The build controller us07ws45510012 - Controller does not contain an enabled build agent with name * and no tags

ERRORS FROM **MS TFS 2010**

Error Three (3)

> Service 'us07ws45510012 - Agent1(OR CONTROLLER)' had an exception: Exception Message: Problem with loading custom assemblies: API restriction: The assembly 'file:///C:\Users\raul.reyes\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildAgent\1\TestProject \obj\Debug\TestProject1.dll' has already loaded from a different location. It cannot be loaded from a new location within the same appdomain.

If you would like to see an VISUAL STUDIO 20120 IMAGE Plese Go [HERE](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3TA6vyvJvAgRWdIM08yU3RfeVE/edit)

Comment: This problem is coming from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996489/how-to-associate-a-build-to-the-test-plan-in-microsoft-test-manager-mtm-2010)

Comment: Hi raulreyes.  Your first two errors suggest that you have a fundamental problem with the configuration of your build machines.  Can you run a simple build with no testing?  Does that build succeed?  I would start by making sure that the basics are working, and add your testing later.

Comment: @Dan Puzey Yes you are right, but how can I get the basics done if TFS Buil Service is not working properly as a "Interactive Process"?

Comment: I don't know, but fix that first - ignore your tests and just get a build to *run*.  Have you even proven that "Interactive process" is the problem yet?

Comment: @Dan Puzey, Yes I tried, is nothing to do with the "interative process" I am have been told that I should correct the path for my .dll but dont know how to do it, I am trying to fix the Error 2, at this point I believe I am going to need to delete and intalls those Agents againg in TFS

Comment: Your errors suggest that the basic configuration of your build agents isn't correct.  Can you create and build a simple console application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding Error #2  (**The build controller [controllerName] does not contain an enabled build agent with name * and no tags**), I encountered this error after re-assigning my Build Controller and creating a new Build Agent that had tags.

**Tags Definition on Build Definition**

There is matching done on the tags defined in the Build Agent definition at the time that a build is run. On the Build Definition, this can be reviewed/configured as follows:

1. In the Visual Studio IDE, under Builds (in Team Explorer), right-click the build definition, and choose "Edit Build Definition..."
2. Under Process, expand "Advanced", then "Agent Settings". Note the "Tags Filter". Here, the tags can be selected, and the build agent will be selected based on the tags.

[image: Build Definition settings, Tags Filter expanded]

In this case, the error indicates that the build definition is looking for "no tags", and an exact match (**MatchExactly**). So, does the Build Agent have tags defined? If so, either remove them from the Build Agent, or configure the Build Definition to use the tags such that a Build Agent will be matched.

**Tags Definition on Build Agent**

Tags are defined on the Build Agent. They may be modified on the TFS build server (based on the build controller, and build agent configured in the Build Definition).

To define/modify tags on the Build Agent, on the TFS Build Server...

1. Start "Team Foundation Server Administration Console"
2. Navigate to "Build Configuration"
3. Locate a Build Agent that is assigned to the Build Controller being used by the Build Definition, and select Properties
4. Tags may be created, added and deleted on the "Build Agent Properties" dialog:

[image: Build Agent tag settings]

Given the pictures above for both Build Definition and Build Agent configuration (with only one Build Agent), this error would result, as the Build Definition expects an exact match  on no tags, and the only Build Agent configured for the Build Controller associated with the Build Definition has a tag defined ('prototype'). Thus there is no exact match on «no tags» and 'prototype'.

Comment: Just want to add on that the "Tag Comparison Operator" in the XAML definition needs to be changed to "MatchAtLeast" if there are more than 1 tags in the Build Agent. For our case, we share several tags into 1 BuildAgent, so we need to use "MatchAtLeast".